# Where can I see the docker-compose output in VS Code remote container?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

In below image VS Code is getting an error running `docker-compose`. When I run that command outside of VS Code it works. Is there a log or a way to see the `docker-compose` output, to see why it is failing in VS Code?

[image]

Comment: I can start the container outside of VS Code and attach to it, but I wanted to get the `devcontainer.json` working to make it easy for other people to use it.